# luis ai(utterances matching multiple intents)

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am working with Luis ai.
I have created multiple intents,utterances,entities.
When I trained the application I found that single utterance is matching with two different intents.Hence I am getting unexpected result.
Is there any solution to resolve the same..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have assigned the same utterance to two different intents?

The quickest way to find out is by using a quick ctrl-F in the Json file.
The Json can be downloaded at the overview [page](https://www.luis.ai/applications) at the right side.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for an utterance to match against different intents. It might be possible to assign the *same utterance* to two different intents via the API, but this isn't possible via the portal.

When you get the response from LUIS, it'll provide the `"topScoringIntent"` along with a list of `"intents"` that are arranged in descending score order.

If the wrong intent has the leading score, then you'll have to retrain the model with this utterance to mark it with the correct intent.